# Why is Android Studio gradle still including library in my apk for google play services analytics when i set to compile only play services Ads?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, android-gradle-plugin, proguard

How can I remove the google play services analytics library from my android studio produced apk? I already did the selective compile com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.3.+

and it did strip out a lot of the other junk, but it still kept services-analytics. I don't use the analytics, how can I get rid of the analytics?

Also how can I get rid of android support-v4 and annotations which I don't use also? (they are not called in gradle files, I do see mention in workspaces.xml as some 'tasks' )

Comment: "I don't use the analytics" -- well, maybe `play-services-ads` does. Ditto with `support-v4`. Run a [Gradle dependency report](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html#sec:listing_dependencies) to see what transitive dependencies are being pulled in.

Comment: ah yea seems like play-services-ads wants to use analytics now go figure..and apparently google-play services wants support-v4 and annotations, was this a change in latest play services 7.3 ?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

> Also how can I get rid of android support-v4 and annotations

You can't. All Play services use some version of support-v4 library (newest at the time of release).

Support annotations do not pollute your apk, it's only a source thing - helps Android Studio with code completion.

> how can I get rid of the analytics?

You don't, `play-services-ads` depends on `play-services-analytics`.

Proguard will remove unused classes so I wouldn't worry much about any of this.

Sauce: Google maven repository in Android SDK.

Comment: thanks yea I discovered that after commonsware comment, I'd upvote you but I don't have enough 'reputation' apparently